# How can I say I am unable to attend in a professional way?

Tags: letter-writing

How can I say "I cannot attend to the award ceremony since Im in abroad" in a professional way.. to ask how can I get my certificate if I unable to attend..

Comment: Are you sure that you mean "attend to"? Also, being "in abroad" has no meaning when written, but a very inappropriate meaning when spoken.Please ask this question on our site for English language learners here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck What appropriate meaning does “in abroad” have when spoken? And how can something be meaningful when spoken, but not when written? Writing is, first and foremost, a representation of spoken language.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Homophones. For "in a broad" - "broad" being American slang for woman - read "engaged in coitus".

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck Oh, I see what you mean now. Yes, that’s true. (Though one might argue whether that’s exactly ‘appropriate’ or not.)

Answer (score 1):

It's Christmas and everyone is nicer... so that's why I'm posting an answer to an off-topic (it lacks any research) question.

> “Due to [unforeseen circumstances](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/due-to-unforeseen-circumstances), I am unable to attend the award ceremony [in person](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-person). Could my certificate [be shipped](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shipped) to me, please?”

If the OP wants to explain what the circumstances are, they can add “I am working/living/visiting a sick relative in [Name of country]” By saying that the circumstances were unforeseen, the speaker is implying that it was their original intention to attend the ceremony. If the intention was not there to begin with then, I'd suggest keeping it simple

> Unfortunately, I am presently in [Name of country] and will not be able to attend the award ceremony. Could my certificate be shipped to me, please?

Definitions

> - **unforeseen circumstances**
>     used in official statements for explaining that something unexpected has happened that will prevent an event or situation from continuing normally
> - **in person**
>     by meeting with someone rather than talking on the phone, e-mailing, or writing to the person:
> - **be shipped**
>     past participle of verb, past tense of verb *[ship](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ship_1)*
>     If people or things **are shipped** somewhere, they are sent there on a ship or by some other means of transport.

References
MacMillan, Cambridge, and Collins dictionaries